# How can I specific linker flag for Package.swift in Swift Package Manager?

Tags: swift-package-manager

I'm trying to running swift project in Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.

Swift is installed from linuxbrew, which using brew's own glibc and dynamic linker(2.35_1):

```
# file /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/swift/5.8.1_1/libexec/bin/swift-frontend
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/swift/5.8.1_1/libexec/bin/swift-frontend: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/ld.so, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
# ll /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/ld.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Dec 14 20:22 /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/ld.so -> /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/glibc/bin/ld.so*
# ll /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/glibc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Dec 14 20:23 /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/glibc -> ../Cellar/glibc/2.35_1/
```

But the output executable will use glibc from system, whose version is to low to run with the executable.

```
# swiftc Sources/main.swift
# file main
main: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
# ./main
./main: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/swift/libexec/lib/swift/linux/libFoundation.so)
./main: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/swift/libexec/lib/swift/linux/libFoundation.so)
./main: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.35' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/swift/libexec/lib/swift/linux/libFoundation.so)
./main: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/swift/libexec/lib/swift/linux/libswiftGlibc.so)
./main: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.35' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/swift/libexec/lib/swift/linux/libswiftGlibc.so)
./main: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/swift/libexec/lib/swift/linux/libdispatch.so)
./main: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/swift/libexec/lib/swift/linux/libdispatch.so)
./main: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/swift/libexec/lib/swift/linux/libdispatch.so)
./main: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/swift/libexec/lib/swift/linux/libswift_Concurrency.so)
./main: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/swift/libexec/lib/swift/linux/libswift_Concurrency.so)
./main: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/swift/libexec/lib/swift/linux/libswiftCore.so)
./main: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/swift/libexec/lib/swift/linux/libswiftCore.so)
./main: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicuuc.so.73)
./main: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicuuc.so.73)
./main: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.35' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current/libgcc_s.so.1)
./main: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current/libgcc_s.so.1)
./main: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current/libstdc++.so.6)
./main: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current/libstdc++.so.6)
./main: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current/libstdc++.so.6)
```

I can add parameters `-Xlinker --dynamic-linker=/home/linuxbrew/.linux brew/lib/ld.so` to `swiftc` to make it work.

This method doesn't work when using `swift build`:

```
# swift build -Xlinker --dynamic-linker=/home/linuxbrew/.linux
brew/lib/ld.so
error: 'cli': Invalid manifest (compiled with: ["/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/swift/5.8.1_1/libexec/bin/swiftc", "-vfsoverlay", "/tmp/TemporaryDirectory.W7O5VK/vfs.yaml", "-L", "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/swift/5.8.1_1/libexec/lib/swift/pm/ManifestAPI", "-lPackageDescription", "-Xlinker", "-rpath", "-Xlinker", "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/swift/5.8.1_1/libexec/lib/swift/pm/ManifestAPI", "-swift-version", "5", "-I", "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/swift/5.8.1_1/libexec/lib/swift/pm/ManifestAPI", "-package-description-version", "5.8.0", "/projects/XXXX/cli/Package.swift", "-Xfrontend", "-disable-implicit-concurrency-module-import", "-Xfrontend", "-disable-implicit-string-processing-module-import", "-o", "/tmp/TemporaryDirectory.Fxjugr/cli-manifest"])
/tmp/TemporaryDirectory.Fxjugr/cli-manifest: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/swift/libexec/lib/swift/linux/libswiftCore.so)
/tmp/TemporaryDirectory.Fxjugr/cli-manifest: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/swift/libexec/lib/swift/linux/libswiftCore.so)
/tmp/TemporaryDirectory.Fxjugr/cli-manifest: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current/libstdc++.so.6)
/tmp/TemporaryDirectory.Fxjugr/cli-manifest: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current/libstdc++.so.6)
/tmp/TemporaryDirectory.Fxjugr/cli-manifest: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current/libstdc++.so.6)
/tmp/TemporaryDirectory.Fxjugr/cli-manifest: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.35' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current/libgcc_s.so.1)
/tmp/TemporaryDirectory.Fxjugr/cli-manifest: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current/libgcc_s.so.1)
/tmp/TemporaryDirectory.Fxjugr/cli-manifest: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/swift/5.8.1_1/libexec/lib/swift/pm/ManifestAPI/../../linux/libFoundation.so)
/tmp/TemporaryDirectory.Fxjugr/cli-manifest: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/swift/5.8.1_1/libexec/lib/swift/pm/ManifestAPI/../../linux/libFoundation.so)
/tmp/TemporaryDirectory.Fxjugr/cli-manifest: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.35' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/swift/5.8.1_1/libexec/lib/swift/pm/ManifestAPI/../../linux/libFoundation.so)
/tmp/TemporaryDirectory.Fxjugr/cli-manifest: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/swift/5.8.1_1/libexec/lib/swift/pm/ManifestAPI/../../linux/libswiftGlibc.so)
/tmp/TemporaryDirectory.Fxjugr/cli-manifest: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.35' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/swift/5.8.1_1/libexec/lib/swift/pm/ManifestAPI/../../linux/libswiftGlibc.so)
/tmp/TemporaryDirectory.Fxjugr/cli-manifest: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/swift/5.8.1_1/libexec/lib/swift/pm/ManifestAPI/../../linux/libdispatch.so)
/tmp/TemporaryDirectory.Fxjugr/cli-manifest: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/swift/5.8.1_1/libexec/lib/swift/pm/ManifestAPI/../../linux/libdispatch.so)
/tmp/TemporaryDirectory.Fxjugr/cli-manifest: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/swift/5.8.1_1/libexec/lib/swift/pm/ManifestAPI/../../linux/libdispatch.so)
/tmp/TemporaryDirectory.Fxjugr/cli-manifest: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/swift/5.8.1_1/libexec/lib/swift/pm/ManifestAPI/../../linux/libswift_Concurrency.so)
/tmp/TemporaryDirectory.Fxjugr/cli-manifest: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/swift/5.8.1_1/libexec/lib/swift/pm/ManifestAPI/../../linux/libswift_Concurrency.so)
/tmp/TemporaryDirectory.Fxjugr/cli-manifest: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicuuc.so.73)
/tmp/TemporaryDirectory.Fxjugr/cli-manifest: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicuuc.so.73)
```

I also add these linker flags to Package.swift:

```
// swift-tools-version: 5.8
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "cli",
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package, defining a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package and products from dependencies.
        .executableTarget(
            name: "cli",
            path: "Sources",
            linkerSettings: [
                 .unsafeFlags(["-Xlinker", "-use-ld=lld", "-Xlinker", "--dynamic-linker=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/ld.so"]),
            ]
            ),
    ]
)
```

Seem like SPM ignore all the flags when compile Package.swift to manifest program.

So how can I make `swift build` normally in my Ubuntu 20 system?